# Trying to reveal hidden text on hover - over the text

Tags: html, css, hover

I'll get straight to the point. What I want to do is to create simple text, such as: `© 2017`, that will change (on hover) to `developed by Jonathan Doe`. I want activation field to be smaller than the deactivation field but the problem is that hitbox for the `© 2017` is the size of hidden element.

I was looking for the solution on the internet for quite some time but everything that I found, was button with not flexible width. Maybe I need to use some sort of tooltip, that will cover passive state? I am not sure.

I want this element to float in the bottom left cornet of the site, that's why I set position to fixed.

The other problem is that when text `developed by Jonathan Doe` is active, deactivation field is bigger on top than it should be. It looks like elements with 0 opacity are messing up my hitboxes. I was trying to play with `display: none;`, but then animation is not playing.

I started to code literally yesterday, so please forgive me for all the noob mistakes. I am trying to understand the logic behind all of this.

I've added the piece of code, I hope I did it right.

```css
.con {
  position: fixed;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  z-index: 99;
}


/* © 2017 */

.con.copyright:before {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 9px 16px 7px 16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  left: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  content: '© 2017';
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.64, 0, .36, 1);
}

.con.copyright:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
  bottom: 32px;
}

.con.copyright:after {
  position: fixed;
  padding: 9px 16px 7px 16px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 26px;
  text-align: left;
  content: 'developed by Jonathan Doe';
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.64, 0, .36, 1);
}

.con.copyright:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
  bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="con copyright"></div>
```

I do not like how you can keep `developed by Jonathan Doe` text active by quickly moving your mouse over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me few additional days but I think I've finally did this. Hitboxes are perfect. The only one problem now is that for some unknown reason, text is not antialiased. I was playing with some values but nothing helped.

**EDIT:** I've came out with better version. Less messy and with working antyaliasing.

Here is the new version - maybe some beginner like myself will find this useful. I will update it if I discover anything new:

**EDIT:** I've: • added `transition-delay` and reversed it so that effect is properly played on `"mouseout"`

**EDIT:** I've: • replaced `visibility: hidden;` with `pointer-events: none;` because with greater `transform: translateY` values `"mouseout"` was glitchy • split `transition: all` to `transition: transform, opacity` and removed `transition-delay` to get better control over delays

**EDIT:** Minor adjustments for better UX

```css
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* copyright */

.copyright {
 position: fixed;
 color: #000000;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 left: 16px;
 top: 16px;
 text-align: left;
 width: 78px;
 height: 42px;
 z-index: 10;
}
.copyright:before {
 pointer-events: none;
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 13px;
 left: 16px;
 opacity: 1;
 content: '© 2017';
 transform: translateY(0px);
 transition: transform .24s 0s ease, opacity .16s .08s ease;
}
.copyright:hover:before {
 transform: translateY(-24px);
 transition: transform .24s 0s ease, opacity .16s 0s ease;
 opacity: 0;
}
.copyright_ch {
 position: absolute;
 opacity: 0;
 padding: 13px 0px 0px 16px;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 pointer-events: none;
 width: 205px;
 transition: transform .24s 0s ease, opacity .16s 0s ease;
 height: 100%;
 transform: translateY(24px);
}
.copyright:hover .copyright_ch {
 opacity: 1;
 pointer-events: auto;
 transform: translateY(0px);
 transition: transform .24s 0s ease, opacity .16s .08s ease
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright"><div class="copyright_ch">developed by Jonathan Doe</div></div>
```

note: This is not really a flexible solution. If you would like to change inscriptions, font size, hitboxes etc., you will have to change and adjust values manually. To get a good look at current hitboxes add `background-color: #cccccc;` to `.copyright` and `.copyright_ch` classes. You might also want to play with `opacity:` `0`/`1` so that you can see what you are working with.